# example of embedding matplotlib in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, qt5, pyqt5

Can anybody show a simple example with basic functionality of embedding matplotlib in PyQt5?

There is PyQt4 example available in official [docs](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html). PyQt4 will soon be [outdated](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro):

> Digia have announced that support for Qt v4 will cease at the end of 2015. PyQt5 and Qt v5 are strongly recommended for all new development.

It could be any general example, say, Qt5 QMainWindow/QWidget + matplotlib line plot.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site. It is for specific questions about specific pieces of code, not "*somebody write some code for me, for free, to the following specifications.*"

Comment: This is mostly the same in Qt5: `curl -L http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.py | sed -r 's@qt4_compat@qt_compat@g;s@([Qq]t)4@\15@g;s@QtGui@QtWidgets@g' | python`

Comment: @MattDMo Firstly, I do not want somebody to write a code for me, I write code only by myself. I asked for simple, short, general example which I can base my code upon. Secondly, say a person wants to make a matplotlib plot in PyQt5 and finds no available example in official docs. Don't you think it would be nice for this site to have such an example available for anybody interested? By the way, I read and use this site as a tutorial to a lot of programming topics as well. Do you think I should stop doing this?

Comment: mpl + Qt5 is only supported for python3.  The qt4 backend is actually implemented as a subclass of the qt5 backend.

Comment: @MattDMo: `"Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site."` For example, it's explicitly stated here [`Stack Overflow F# Tutorial`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/f%23/info). So it's a tutorial site also. :))

Answer (score 3):

what you might be looking for, can be found here: [embedded matplotlib in PyQt](https://web.archive.org/web/20161123064745/http://blog.rcnelson.com/building-a-matplotlib-gui-with-qt-designer-part-1/). It's a blog of one of matplotlib's developers. It is stil written for PyQt4 but it turned out that one just has to change all `PyQt4's` to 5 and replace `QtGui` with `QtWidtgets`. I talked to Ryan and send him the updated code. He was pleased to see that there are people who aknowledge his effort and will updated his `tutorial`.

Since I had the same problem and was looking around for some solutions to get a start, I found [zedcode PyQt5 Introductory Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/) which doesn't cover `matplotlib` but can be combined and helps to understand.

Finally, let me say something aobut what one has to do to get matplotlib plots into a Gui.
Ryan's tut points out, that one has to build a normal `QWidget` which will hold the `canvas`. You can do that with `Qt Creator`.
The part where gui and matplotlib join is the following:

```
def addmpl(self, fig):
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    self.mplvl.addWidget(self.canvas)
    self.canvas.draw()
```

mplvl is just the empty `QWidget` which gets the `FigureCanvas` and is shown afterwards.
For my own app, I wanted to show a 3D-plot, but there are some issues with dropping the mouse support, so there could be some problems left. All 2D plots turned out to be fully functional.

Have a try.

Christian