# PyQt5: Looking for example of Embedding external app window in Application

Tags: python, pyqt5, embed

I have a largeish application I'm developing in Python3 using PyQt5. I want to do something very much like what is being done here in PyQt4:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import atexit

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class XTerm(QX11EmbedContainer):

    def __init__(self, parent, xterm_cmd="xterm"):
        QX11EmbedContainer.__init__(self, parent)
        self.xterm_cmd = xterm_cmd
        self.process = QProcess(self)
        self.connect(self.process,
                     SIGNAL("finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)"),
                     self.on_term_close)
        atexit.register(self.kill)

    def kill(self):
        self.process.kill()
        self.process.waitForFinished()

    def sizeHint(self):
        size = QSize(400, 300)
        return size.expandedTo(QApplication.globalStrut())

    def show_term(self):
        args = [
            "-into",
            str(self.winId()),
            "-bg",
            "#000000",  # self.palette().color(QPalette.Background).name(),
            "-fg",
            "#f0f0f0",  # self.palette().color(QPalette.Foreground).name(),
            # border
            "-b", "0",
            "-w", "0",
            # blink cursor
            "-bc",
        ]
        self.process.start(self.xterm_cmd, args)
        if self.process.error() == QProcess.FailedToStart:
            print "xterm not installed"

    def on_term_close(self, exit_code, exit_status):
        print "close", exit_code, exit_status
        self.close()
```

(from https://bitbucket.org/henning/pyqtwi...11/terminal.py)

- which is: Embed an X11 shell terminal (xterm) into a tab of my application.

I understand that **QX11EmbedContainer** is not in PyQt5, and that some usage of **createWindowContainer** may be the new approach, but I cannot find any example of this in action to follow.

I would ideally like to see the above code ported to a fully functional example using PyQt5 conventions and methods, but any assistance in any form will be helpful.

I have looked at [Embedding external program inside pyqt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728941/embedding-external-program-inside-pyqt5), but there is only a win32 solution there, and I need to run on Linux and MacOS, with windows being an unnecessary nicety, if there was a generalized solution to fit all 3.  It feels like this is close, but I cannot find the appropriate replacement for the **win32gui** module to use in a general implementation.

I have looked at [example of embedding matplotlib in PyQt5 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357442/example-of-embedding-matplotlib-in-pyqt5), but that pertains to matplotlib in particular, and not the general case.

All pointers and help will be gratefully acknowledged.

Comment: Spyder IDE has IPython console inside it, and it is written in PyQt5. Maybe you can look in here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/master/spyder/widgets/ipythonconsole/shell.py

Comment: Basically, IDEs written in PyQt5 may be the best places to look, since they almost invariably need to embed terminal applications and the such on all platforms.

Comment: The pyqt5 example works fine for me on linux. Just remove all the win32 junk and set `hwnd` to an appropriate window id. Your real question is: "how do I find the window id of an external application"? There are plenty of tools available on linux for doing that, and you already have a working example for windows. I have no idea about macos, though.

Comment: These are great pointers!  Thanks.

@ekhumoro - I have been trying what you suggest (prior to posting the question) - using 'xwininfo' on MacOS (which is very like *NIX flavours) to get the window ID of a running xterm instance.  No luck yet.  Could you post the modified code you got working, please?

Comment: @mahesh - while Spyder does indeed incorporate a terminal shell, it appears to do so with a full implementation of a terminal, where I want to just drop in an external xwindows app, like xterm - without implementing the whole thing.

Comment: @CalebHoward. Modified code? You mean like `QWindow.fromWinId(0x2e00018)`? That will work on linux, but I have no idea whether anything so simple will work on macos. Did `QX11EmbedContainer` work on macos?

Comment: @ekhumoro Yeah - like that.  :-)  That's what I was doing (essentially) - with the result being 

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSTaggedDate window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000d'`

So I guess it's not working under MacOS.  

Still looking for a solution, then.  Back-burnering the feature for now.

Comment: @ekhumoro I tried the same in Linux mentioned here `(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474647/run-a-foreign-exe-inside-a-python-gui-pyqt)`. For some application, it is coming without any issues but others, such as Rviz, when run as a Qprocess, the whole window is not showing. Only a part is showing. Any idea why ?

Comment: @Sid133 Qt doesn't really support embedding *external* windows: see my comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58816766/how-to-embed-a-pptk-viewer-in-a-pyqt5-window#comment104172619_58937338).